# How to include tex files

Tags: formatting, input, include

Is there any way that I can add different `.tex` files (From different folders) into another folder's `.tex` file?

I meant that  all of  the `.tex` files will be fine and separated  and I just need to aggregate into one without copy & pasting these files into a single one.

[image]

I have saved the input file like this, but it's not working when I write in another file,
like [image]

```
\include{oscillonsource.tex}.
```

It's still not working. :-(

Comment: combine documentclass can do it.

Comment: For a good specific answer simple [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) might help. For eg: What would be the absolute/relative paths of `child1.tex`,`child2.tex` files with respect to `master.tex` ? What is the preamble in `child.tex` files and are they self-compilable with their own `\documentclass{}` ? [TeX UK faq website](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multidoc) has some excellent information on it

Comment: Please post the contents of the oscillonsource.tex file and of the file in which you want to include oscillonsource.tex

Comment: @compex-guy If you use `\input{}`, you could write path to the file, e.g., if you have your tex file in the forder WORK, but there are subfolders CH1, CH2, etc., use `\input{CH1/sec1.tex}` and so on! Cheers.

Comment: \input{oscillon130613/oscillonsource.tex} 

I inserted the above one, but didn't work. My file name is oscillon13061  and tex file name is oscillonsource.tex.

Comment: Change `\input{oscillon130613/...}` to  `\input{../oscillon130613/...}`. `..` is the Unix shortcut for the parent folder relative to your working directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a complete example of the input/include command at work:

The example consists of 3 files in a folder structure as follows:

```
[Parent Folder]
 |
 +-- file1.tex
 |
 +-- fig.jpg
 |
 +-- [folder]
      |
      +-file2.tex
```

`fig.jpg` is just an ordinary jpg image file. The contents of `file1.tex` are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{folder/file2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Note the inclusion of the (relative) path as well as the filename of `file2.tex`.

The contents of file2.tex are

```
\includegraphics{fig.jpg}
```

Note that `file2.tex` does *not* have its own preamble, document class, `\begin{document}` etc.

Think of `\input` as having a similar effect to you manually copying and pasting whatever is in `file2.tex` into `file1.tex`: no need to include anything you wouldn't want to copy in this fashion. Following through this copying/pasting logic: note also that the path to `fig.jpg` needs to be relative to `file1.tex`, not `file2.tex`. Since `fig.jpg` is in the same folder as `file1.tex` this means that we don't have to specify any path.

Saving this file/folder structure and compiling `file1.tex` results in a document with `fig.jpg` included in it.

Comment: If I want to open  the tex file, then I need to open three folders, my tex file name is oscillonsource.tex and it is placed on the last opened folder, oscillon130613  .

Comment: \date{July 07, 2013}     
\begin{document} \baselineskip=16pt

\input{oscillon130613/oscillonsource.tex}

\end{document}

But didn't work.

Comment: I think problem is in my input cause when I insert it, then the tex file is not running.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the `\include{<filename>}` command inserts the file  after a page break. If you don't want the page break, use `\input{<filename>}`. The major reason you would want to use `\include` rather than `\input` is the [`\includeonly`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/24113) command, which can save compilation time when writing your document.

Comment: a tex file name  "oscillon source.tex"  and I have write in another file like this \include{<oscillon source.tex>} , but didn't work. 
Do I need to insert these file in thje same folder. ?

Comment: You don't need the angle brackets (they're just to indicate it's a placeholder), and you don't need the extension: use \include{oscillon source}

Comment: **Don't** use filenames with spaces with `\include`...

Comment: I wrote  \include{oscillon source}  and the file opened but cant see any element of that file in the new file :-(

Comment: @karlkoeller you told me to to give any space between filenames?
Can you elaborate please?

Comment: TeX doesn't like spaces in file names; you'll have to rename the file oscillonsource.tex, and then `\include` it, as `\include{oscillonsource.tex}`.

Comment: Done as you say but It's not working.

Comment: I've tried it on my system, and `\include` isn't working for me either, which is strange. However, `\input` works, although it lacks the advanced features

Comment: @ComplexGuy: we are plainly not understanding what you have written.  rename "oscillon source.tex" as "oscillon-source.tex", and write a latex file that's as small as possible, and shows the error: that way ("minimal example") we see what your problem is, not your description of your problem.

Comment: Do I have to write something in the beginning as I wrote   \usepackage{graphicx}  when I added graphics.